# Funding for a podium

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> **JENNY:** Listen, I don't think we can afford the podium after all.
>
> *Brian has a confused look on his face as Jenny peels a page full of numbers from her notepad and hands it to him.*
>
> **JENNY:** PM's been very clear about the budget. It's been codified right from the get-go. See, we have to reserve this amount here for a proper underfloor heating system. We can still finish the house within budget if we get rid of the big podium in the meeting room.
>
> *Brian looks at the numbers.*
>
> **BRIAN:** There's no way a UFH system is this expensive. There has to be a cheaper solution. We just have to take a moment to analyze... Ensure that we have enough for both the UFH and the podium.
>
> **JENNY:** You do understand that a full UFH's absolutely essential to have here. A podium's not. Just recently PM urged us to save money wherever possible. He doesn't want to see the costs skyrocket like in the last project. You're going to have to say bye bye podium.
>
> **BRIAN:** But... But...

Something's missing here. What kind of ending should this story have?

Hint:

> Six short clues are hiding in the text. One is missing.

Comment: *Brian has a confused look on **her** face* : Brian is a firstname most often given to boys. Should we assume Brian is female, or is it a typo, or does it not matter ?

Comment: @Evargalo Fixed, thanks. Just a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story should have a ...

> ... **happy** ending. Perhaps this one:
>
>  BRIAN: But... But... Wait! All this tight budgeting is done via Project Accounting. You know how they have treated us throughout this project. Can't we just gyp PA? Have some of the costs moved to other accounts? Look ...
>
>  Brian takes the notepad from Jenny and points out some numbers to her. Jenny frowns as she looks at the numbers thoughtfully.
>
>  JENNY: Yes, that might actually work ...

Eh?

> The names of six of the seven dwarfs from Walt Disney's Snow White are hidden backwards in the text. The one who is missing is Happy:
>
>  JENNY: Listen, I don't think we can afford the podium after all.
>
>  Brian has a confused look on his face as Jenn**Y PEELS** a page full of numbers from her notepad and hands it to him.
>
>  JENNY: PM's been very clear about the budget. It's been **COD**ified right from the get-go. See, we have to reserve this amount here for a proper underfloor heating system. We can still finish the house within budget if we get rid of the big podium in the meeting room.
>
>  Brian looks at the numbers.
>
>  BRIAN: There's no way a UFH system is this expensive. There has to be a cheaper solution. We just have to take a moment to anal**YZE... ENS**ure that we have enough for both the UFH and the podium.
>
>  JENNY: You do understand that a ful**L UFH'S AB**solutely essential to have here. A podium's not. Just recentl**Y PM URG**ed us to save money wherever possible. He doesn't want to see the costs skyrocket like in the last project. You're going to have to say bye b**YE POD**ium.
>
>  BRIAN: But... But...

Relevant xkcd:

> [image: The days of the week are Monday, Arctic, Wellesley, Green, Electra, Synergize, and the Seventh Seal.]
>
>  (Click image to have it explained.)

Comment: Nice work! I *told* you that the clues were short! :P

Comment: Yuk. Random short term search in full text! How did you get the first one or an inkling on what to search for? I’d possibly looked around UFH first, but else? Well done though!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they are discussing

> Building a chicken house (coop).

Underfloor heating

> would be important and beneficial to the chickens, especially in the colder climates

A podium in the meeting room

> may be a place for chickens to roost upon, not essential though.  If it were a human meeting room, it would be more important

The PM

> may be the project manager or the poultry manager

And

> bye bye podium may be a reference to bye bye birdie?

So the end of the story

> The chicken coop is built, the birds are warm, the farmer is happy and Brian can try to put a podium in the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jenny suggests at first that they cannot afford to buy a new podium, some details suggest there is already a podium there:

- She says to "***get rid of*** the **big** podium"
- She also tells Brian to say "*bye bye*" to the podium.

Also, Jenny speaks of a previous project that went over budget.

Could it be that this project is not *building* a house from the ground up, but *refurbishing* one built previously? Could the "*big*" podium referred to be an existing one that was going to be replaced by a new, *smaller* podium? One reason for this may be that the underfloor heating will raise the floor level and make the existing podium too high.

If this is correct then the story could end with a comprimise of having the "big" podium lowered rather than buying a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the PM only wants underfloor heating because he/she gets cold feet when they stand at the podium. Sure, they can't afford the new podium as well as the underfloor heating, but removing the podium would negate the need for the underfloor heating in the first place.

Brian knows this and that is why he is protesting the decision to fit the UFH but not the podium.